# unable to create new fields after upgrading masterpage to 2010

Tags: master-page, upgrade

I am unable to create new fields in existing lists after upgrading my 2007 master page to 2010. I get an error which says

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.0.04506.03; InfoPath.2;
>   .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR
>   3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8;
>   .NET4.0C) Timestamp: Mon, 12 Jul 2010
>   13:45:13 UTC
>
> Message: 'undefined' is null or not an
>   object Line: 1281 Char: 4 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://sharepoint2010/_layouts/fldNew.aspx?List=%7B94C7D5B0%2D781A%2D44C1%2DA865%2DE3D0C0629EB9%7D

My master page is located here
http://pastie.org/1040873

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the following tag outside the form

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server" />
```

Comment: It also works for me thanks...i have followed same steps for completing this